# gdb + gfortran in macos Big sur hangs forever

Tags: macos, gdb, gfortran, macos-big-sur

Does gdb work in macOS Big Sur? I followed all installation instructions and got it codesigned. After I load a very simple code that's supposed to add two variables, it hangs forever after I set a breakpoint and type "run" (see output below). I have even tried to compile gdb from source.

```
Reading symbols from ./a.out...
Reading symbols from /Users/andya/Downloads/a.out.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/a.out...
(gdb) b 6
Breakpoint 1 at 0x100003e2f: file aa.f90, line 6.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /Users/andya/Downloads/a.out
[New Thread 0x5403 of process 45117]
```

Comment: You need to tell us where you got your gdb. How did you install it? Which version is it?

Comment: You should also tell us whether or not your program runs without gdb.

Comment: Hi, yes the program runs properly without gdb. I got  gdb (latest version, 10.1) using "brew instal gdb" and I also compiled the source from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/